# SSL keys and client auth in Java

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, authentication

I am connecting to a webservice SSL client auth, I set up the keystore by:

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", 
                                  "d:/banking/BankClient/classes/xxcompany/bank/certificate/keystore.jks");
System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");
```

When calling the webservice:

```
GetAccountBalanceResponse resp = services.getAccountBalance(request);
```

I get a following error

```
WARNING:Cannot connecti with url: https://[redacted] ; reason: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is: 
    HTTP transport error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at xxcompany.bank.proxy.runtime.ServicesBinding_Stub.getAccountBalance(ServicesBinding_Stub.java:146)
    at xxcompany.bank.proxy.ServicesPortClient.getAccountBalance(ServicesPortClient.java:48)
    at xx.bank.client.main(client.java:111)
Caused by: HTTP transport error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.http.HttpClientTransport.invokeImpl(HttpClientTransport.java:174)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.http.HttpClientTransport.invoke(HttpClientTransport.java:150)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._sendImpl(StreamingSender.java:176)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._send(StreamingSender.java:113)
    at xxcompany.bank.proxy.runtime.ServicesBinding_Stub.getAccountBalance(ServicesBinding_Stub.java:130)
    ... 2 more
```

The keystore containes the private certificate for the client, the certificate is valid and works fine when used in the browser. How should I fix it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when the CA which signed the server cert is either not one of the well know CAs or the public certificate of the CA is not in the trust store of the client.  To get around this you will have to add the public certificate of the CA to the trust store of the client.

See [unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification) and [No more 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) for detailed instructions.